# Found no syntax as guide in XlsxWriter documentation

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

My environment summary -

1. Visual Studio Code version 1.5.0 last update 2020-10-07
2. XlsxWriter 1.3.7
3. Python 3.8.1

I'm newbies for Python and XlsxWriter, i follow all steps in Getting Started with XlsxWriter (https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html). Here is my code on my VS Code -

> import xlsxwriter
>
> workbook =
> xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Python\Test1.xlsx')
> workbook = workbook.add_worksheet()
>
> workbook._write_worksheet('A1','Hello World') --> (1)
>
> workbook.close()--> (2)

when compared with source document on XlsxWriter site as code below

> import xlsxwriter
>
> workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx') worksheet =
> workbook.add_worksheet()
>
> worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')
>
> workbook.close()

My questions are

1. at (1) i found no syntax ".worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello World')" but I found this syntax instead "._write_worksheet()"
2. at (2) i also found no syntax ".close()" syntax

please advice me what steps i did wrong as i follow all instruction from XlsxWriter Documentation

thanks a lot